# Any plans to update sIFR to AS3?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, sifr, sifr3

In my experience, the text rendering is better in flash 9/10 AS3. Are there any plans to get sIFR working with AS3?

Comment: I found this other question that may be related. Hope it helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2822884/anyone-able-to-translate-sifr-into-as3-for-hyphenation-and-with-the-help-of-a-c

Answer (score 1):

You should ask Mark Wubben that, not us. You can contact him via the form on http://novemberborn.net/about or via twitter at http://twitter.com/novemberborn

Answer (score 1):

But, to answer here, no plans from me, no.