# Anyone able to translate sIFR into AS3 (for hyphenation and with the help of a converter)?

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript-2, sifr, translate, hyphenation

One thing asked for a lot with sIFR is hyphenation.

Now I almost solved it with integrating Hyphenator.as http://vis4.net/blog/2010/05/as3-hyphenation/.

The only problem is that Hyphenator.as is written in AcionScript 3, while sIFR is in ActionScript 2.

I found an AS2 to AS3 converter www.5etdemi.com/blog/archives/2006/11/as2-to-as3-converter-createtextfield-geturl-handling/ but the result examples.bezel.be/sIFR-as3.as is not working yet.

Anyone able to contribute to making hyphenation work in sIFR?

(Sorry for the links, but weirdly I am only allowed to post one link. Really weird.)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately it's not that easy. AS2 and AS3 are substantially different languages, with different API's into the flash player. It's not just a simple renaming or different syntax, the fundamental way many things work has changed.

Why do you need hyphenation for sIFR? I thought the point of sIFR was for headings, things that shouldn't be wrapping in the first place, and not for big blocks of text.

Comment: Well, the thing is that even the most professional font looks so horrible that it is unusable with @font-face while rendered with Flash every font looks great. The only fonts that look good with @font-face are the Microsoft fonts (must be because of the hinting), so I'm stuck with those right now.

The only way to use the font I actually chose is sIFR, and: it does works great on big blocks of text.

Comment: Maybe it's easier to port Hyphenator to AS2?